# Inserting image-url as resized image blob data into database with good performance

Tags: php, mysql

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
"image-url","text1","text2","text3","text4"
```

This should be inserted into a mysql-database as

```
content-of-image-as-blob,"text1","text2","text3","text4"
```

I used to do it via php, ie

1. Read image-url
2. Resize to within 150 x 150 pixels while maintaining aspect ratio
3. convert to blob-data, ie 0x225332525....
4. Insert into mysql-database

I found this to take a long time when the csv file has more than 1000 lines and the script to stop prematurely (even though max-execution-time is set to 2 hours, it aborted after about 10 minutes). Images are around 10 to 60KB each. So using the transmission speeds of servers for say 1000 lines this amounts to 1000 * 60KB, just 60 Megabytes max. Should be one minute with 1MB/s and much less at a server's speed.

How do I convert

```
"image-url","text1","text2","text3","text4"
```

into

```
content-of-image-as-blob,"text1","text2","text3","text4"
```

with better performance than how I do it and without it aborting?

**Edit**: That's my current approach

*upload.php:*

```
<?php
    function BildInBLOB($linkadresse)
    {
        $maxsize = 65536;   

      $data = file_get_contents('kleiner.php?link='.urlencode($linkadresse)); //kleiner.php further down
      $serialized_data = serialize($data);

      $size = strlen($serialized_data);

        if ($size < $maxsize) {
            $imgData  = mysql_escape_string($data);
            return $imgData;        
        }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }

   //$felder[0] = image-url

    $kopfzeilenfelder = get_headers($felder[0]);

    if (isset($kopfzeilenfelder[7]))
    {
      if ($kopfzeilenfelder[7] == "Content-Type: image/jpeg" || $kopfzeilenfelder[7] == "Content-Type: image/gif" || $kopfzeilenfelder[7] == "Content-Type: image/png")
      {

        $imageurl = BildInBLOB($felder[0]);
        if ($imageurl == false)
                      mail('test@test.de','Error',$felder[0]);
        $imageurl_typ = returnMIMEType($felder[0]);

          //Einfügen in Datenbank
            $abfragetext = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`content-of-image-as-blob`, `text1`,`text2`,`text3`,`text4`) VALUES (\''.$imageurl.'\', \''.$text1.'\', \''.$text2.'\', \''.$text3.'\', \''.$text4.'\');';

          $abfrage_ergebnis = mysql_query($abfragetext);
      }
      else
      {
        $fehler = true;
      }
    }
    else
    {
        $fehler = true;
        break;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

*kleiner.php:*

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
   require('SimpleImage.php');
   $image = new SimpleImage();
   $image->load($_GET['link']);
   if ($image->getWidth() > $image->getHeight())
   {    
      $ratio = $width / $image->getWidth();
      $height = $image->getheight() * $ratio;
   }
   else
   {
      $ratio = $height / $image->getHeight();
      $width = $image->getWidth() * $ratio;
   }      
   $image->resize($width,$height);
   $image->output();
?>
```

EDIT: Measuring imageurl

```
$time_start = microtime(true);   


$imageurl = BildInBLOB($felder[0]);



$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
$datei_handle=fopen('loeschen.txt',"a");
fwrite($datei_handle,$time."\n");
fclose($datei_handle);
```

results in

```
4.0833919048309
0.49023699760437
1.4829730987549
0.46650505065918
1.6500248908997
1.6888198852539
1.7747900485992
1.7654030323029
1.7827639579773
1.6984438896179
1.7959661483765
0.5819149017334
1.5812880992889
0.477952003479
0.48433899879456
0.49926495552063
2.6636629104614
1.6903870105743
0.47167086601257
0.59404015541077
0.4657621383667
0.48750114440918
1.5725650787354
0.67707896232605
0.57791996002197
0.69522404670715
3.727931022644
0.59935402870178
0.47536182403564
0.5656099319458
0.74236917495728
0.57420802116394
0.58336305618286
2.6896998882294
2.6945810317993
0.55907297134399
1.1201891899109
0.60288882255554
0.55426001548767
5.7161459922791
4.6411039829254
0.61310982704163
0.63013315200806
2.6628720760345
0.59778094291687
0.58457708358765
0.45639109611511
0.6767098903656
0.67303490638733
0.61607003211975
0.69722104072571
1.5636711120605
0.66522693634033
3.5140080451965
0.58035182952881
0.575355052948
0.60047006607056
0.59423995018005
2.5612559318542
3.721363067627
3.5471968650818
3.5297789573669
0.56819891929626
1.667160987854
0.70830678939819
0.55341696739197
0.76275014877319
0.88022589683533
1.9490652084351
0.96493005752563
1.0359950065613
2.3565669059753
1.7734251022339
1.8485751152039
0.51054096221924
0.77539587020874
2.6769950389862
1.6807489395142
0.47317314147949
0.45396709442139
0.5827260017395
0.67431807518005
0.45959377288818
0.58339309692383
1.4438741207123
0.58361291885376
1.5400068759918
1.639084815979
1.6939740180969
0.56597709655762
0.70935010910034
0.5993390083313
0.47545599937439
0.61747407913208
0.60248994827271
0.61786508560181
0.58388590812683
0.47097396850586
0.60158681869507
0.58294200897217
0.60332798957825
1.7215020656586
0.67375087738037
0.60588788986206
0.68769884109497
0.7059919834137
0.45914888381958
0.56948590278625
0.57627296447754
0.46779298782349
0.46954989433289
0.57487106323242
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents('image')` to get the binary data of the image. Do a `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to get the escaping right and use this data in the query.

```
$data = file_get_contents($image);
$data_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($data);
```

Makew sure you use the right command for escaping, depending on mysql/mysqli/pdo/etc.

**edit**

As I forgot to react to the resizing part: Use [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/function.imagecopyresampled.php), there are plenty of examples for that on the manual pages.
To get the raw data you have to use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource, null, 90);
$raw_image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Remember, when outputting the image from the database, you have to send the correct header corresponding to the image type.

```
header('image/jpeg');
echo $blob_data;
```

Comment: Where does the resizing take place?

Comment: Oh, sorry - thought that the resizing was optional and the question aimed at the "get binary data" point. Gimme a sec

Comment: Habe den Hauptpost aktualisiert, ich scheine das bereits so zu machen, bis auf ob_start(); Findest du Geschwindigkeitshindernisse in meinem Code?

Comment: Meß mal die Zeit die beim `$image->load()` vergeht. >> http://de2.php.net/microtime

Comment: Habe den Hauptpost aktualisiert

Comment: Du solltest nicht deine eigene Datei `kleiner.php` per `file_get_contents` holen. Mach alles in einer Datei. Dein Server brauch fast eine Sekunde um die Anwort an ihn selbst zu beantworten. Grunliegend weist das auf ein lokales Auflösungsproblem hin. Aber mach mal alles in einer Datei...